# In Excel, how to compare 1 cell against a column of values in two workbooks

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, vlookup

Tried to find an answer but could not - I am an excel novice.

Our company put on a webinar, we received excel spreadsheet of attendees, names company names, etc.

I am tasked with comparing the Attendee list/spreadsheet with our company CRM database to see if they are already in the system. Comparing by company name only.

I created an export from our CRM system of all companies we have in the CRM system as a single column excel file (column A, company name, 732 lines).

I need to compare the CRM export xls column A to the Attendee Spreadsheet, Company Name (column E2-E180) and flag each one that already exists in the CRM system.

i would like to put a "NO MATCH" or "MATCH" text on the Attendee Sheet in column F on the row of the company that was not found.

Can anyone give some suggestions/formulas so I do not have to perform this manually one by one.

Answer (score 5):

```
=IF(COUNTIF($D$2:$D$5,A2)>0, "Match", "No Match")
```

Use this where D2:D5 is the list of existing companies and A2 is the cell containing the company that you want to search for.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(start_cell_value_to_compare:end_cell_value_to_compare,compare_to_start_cell:compare_to_end_cell,0)),"true","false")
```

Here is the example like, I've one column name "F" and match whole column into different column name "D", then i wrote looks like,

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(F2:F753,$D2:D9706,0)),"true","false")
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: This does not even seem to attempt to answer. It reads like a description of your own problem. Please make the answering part more obvious.